# Zend Naviagtion/Menu

Tags: zend-framework

Im trying to figure out the best way to keep track of my navigation for a site im working on.

I already use Zend Navigation to render a top menu with drop down submenus. This works fine.  However I also want to keep track of my menu items which apply directly to a single item/model which the above menu displays.  For instance my menu now.

```
<nav>
  <job>
     <label>Jobs</label>
     <resource>job</resource>
     <controller>job</controller>
     <action>list</action>
     <pages>
        .....
     </pages>
  <job>
</nav>
```

This works good for handling "menus" which do not ally to a specific record in database.  It is possible to keep track of the "actions" that are carried out on individual records.  These extra items should not be rendered inside the main navigation as they only have context with a certain id, but could be rendered as a menu when viewing a record.

so maybe like:

```
<nav>
   <resource>
     <menu items to be rendered without specific context>
       <possible submenu items>
       </possible submenu items>
     </menu items to be rendered without specific context>
     <menu items to be rendered inside a specific context(like viewings a record)>
        <view></view>
        <edit></edit>
        <invoice></invoice>
     </menu items to be rendered inside a specific context(like viewings a record)>
   </resource>
</nav>
```

I was thinking I could have a separate .xml for my context specific menu items but I would like to keep the resources grouped together.

Comment: Can you give your question a title that is more descriptive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a drill down menu? You can do it easily with CSS. Example: (I prefer arrays but you can adjust).

Create your navigation as you normally would but ensure you set the subitems for each action:

```
$menu = array(
    array(
        'label' => 'Add Booking',
        'module' => 'booking',
        'controller' => 'admin',
        'action' => 'addBooking',
        'route' => 'default',
        'pages'=>array(
            array(
                'label'=>'test',
                'module' => 'booking',
                'controller' => 'admin',
                'action' => 'anotheraction',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

CSS:

```
ul.navigation li ul li {
    display:none;
}
ul.navigation li.active ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

As long as you set the parameters for the parent page correctly it will should work fine.

Comment: No I would like to be able to use zend navigation in certain contexts

Comment: Zend navigation accepts multiple types of data, an array is one. As I said, you can ignore my array example, it just shows how to nest pages correctly. The css is all you need.